# No such file or directory error using mkdir

Tags: php

I am encounter with a problem when i give full path to mkdir it says No such file or directory but when i am providing the same back but first going back to one directory it work

I am just want to ask why this is not working

```
$name = "4ftwx"; // dir name 

$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
mkdir($domain.'/project/'.$name);

     //localhost/project/4ftwx
```

but it work when i call like this

```
mkdir('../project/'.$name);
```

both pointing same path then why it is not working

Comment: It's because you can't use `http://` with `mkdir`, plain and simple. It must be a relative path.

Comment: then what is the solution

Comment: What do you mean by a solution, what exactly do you wish to achieve?

Comment: i just want to give full path to mkdir instead of placing `../`

Comment: i have a name of the folder and i want to create it without focusing where is the code . it work from any page

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the document root directory under which the current script is executing.